# How to not show stack trace in Gulp task error callback?

Tags: node.js, gulp

When I error out in one of my tasks:

```
gulp.task('foo', function(onDone) {
    onDone('It did not work');
});
```

I get a large irrelevant stack trace:

```
[13:10:25] 'foo' errored after 4.27 s
[13:10:25] Error: It did not work
    at formatError (C:\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:195:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (D:\Code\my-project\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at D:\Code\my-project\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (D:\Code\my-project\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (D:\Code\my-project\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
    at D:\Code\my-project\gulp-tasks\insert-docs.js:116:25
    at Request._callback (D:\Code\my-project\gulpfile.js:112:17)
```

How do I not show that? I'd prefer to use the in build gulp features rather than a third party module or `console.error()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gulp [checks for the presence of a `showStack` property](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/71953b58ee8077ee882272d1834e3f0ded9a2b92/bin/gulp.js#L159) on `Error` objects passed to the callback. This was probably introduced to support that option on [`gutil.PluginError`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util#new-pluginerrorpluginname-message-options), but can be used with any `Error` object:

```
function withError(msg) {
  var err = new Error(msg);
  err.showStack = false;
  return err;
}

gulp.task('foo', function(done) {
  done(withError('It did not work'));
});
```